# How to select drop-down value in Protractor using framework: 'jasmine',

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to select drop down list using protractor. None of this code works.

```
it("Select Block from District", function() {

    const selectElement={}
    selectElement.selectElementDropdown =function(element,index,milliseconds){
     console.log("Selecting element by drop down","OK");

     element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options){

         options[2].click(); 
    //here index 2 is hardcoded, which can be changed to options[index]
     });

     if(typeof milliseconds!=='undefined'){
         browser.sleep(milliseconds);
     }

    }

    module.exports =selectElement;

    const methodDropDown = {} //require('../Src/SelectElement.js');

    var DistrictDetails = function(){

    this.DistrictName = element.all(by.xpath("//label[text()='Select Block']")).get(7).element(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Ambabhona')]"));
    //the selector is clicked to open the drop down
```

I have already gone through pass the value using send keys to text box

```
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-sm-6">
    <label _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-md-5 control-label">District
        <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="err-msg">*</span>
    </label>
    <div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-md-7">
        <p-dropdown _ngcontent-c9="" formcontrolname="districtId" placeholder="Select District"
            class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
            <div class="ng-tns-c6-189 ui-dropdown ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"
                style="width: 138px;">
                <!---->
                <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted">
                    <select class="ng-tns-c6-189" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label=" ">
                        <!---->
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted">Select District</option>
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <!---->
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="390" style="">Bargarh</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="391" style="">Jharsuguda</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="392" style="">Sambalpur</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="393" style="">Deogarh</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="394" style="">Sundergarh</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="395" style="">Keonjhar</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="396" style="">Mayurbhanj</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="397" style="">Balasore</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="398" style="">Bhadrak</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="399" style="">Kendrapara</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="400" style="">Jagatsinghpur</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="401" style="">Cuttack</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="402" style="">Jajpur</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="403" style="">Dhenkanal</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="404" style="">Angul</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="405" style="">Nayagarh</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="406" style="">Khordha</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="407" style="">Puri</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="408" style="">Ganjam</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="409" style="">Gajapati</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="410" style="">Kandhamal</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="411" style="">Boudh</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="412" style="">Sonepur</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="413" style="">Bolangir</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="414" style="">Nuapada</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="415" style="">Kalahandi</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="416" style="">Rayagada</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="417" style="">Nabarangpur</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="418" style="">Koraput</option>
                        <option class="ng-tns-c6-189 ng-star-inserted" value="419" style="">Malkangiri</option>
                        <!---->
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input class="ng-tns-c6-189" readonly="" role="listbox" type="text" aria-label=" ">
                </div>
                <!---->
                <!----><label
                    class="ng-tns-c6-189 ui-dropdown-label ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-placeholder ng-star-inserted">
                    Select District
                </label>
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <div class="ui-dropdown-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span
                        class="ui-dropdown-trigger-icon ui-clickable pi pi-caret-down"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="ng-tns-c6-189 ui-dropdown-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ng-trigger ng-trigger-panelState"
                    style="display: none; z-index: 1181; top: 27px; left: 0px; opacity: 0;">
                    <!---->
                    <div class="ui-dropdown-items-wrapper" style="max-height: 200px;">
                        <!---->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p-dropdown>
        <!---->
    </div>
</div>
```

Want to select value form drop-down list like  Deogarh

Answer (score 0):

usually either of described approached work. Note I'm using `async/await` in my code

## 1. Easy way

Declare js click (inject script in console). and then just click any option directly

```
let jsClick = ($element) => browser.executeScript(
    "arguments[0].click();",
    $element.getWebElement()
);

let $option = $("option[value='395']");

await jsClick($option);
```

This injected click works differently then protractor `.click()`. It may click elements even if they are mot visible. Works, but not really UI verification

## 2. What user would do

Requires scrolling

```
let scroll = ($element, offsetY = 0) => browser.executeScript(
        `arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
        window.scroll(
            0,window.scrollY-50-(${offsetY})
        );`,
        $element.getWebElement()
     );

await $visibleDropdown.click();
await scroll($yourOption);
await $yourOption.click();
```

Let me know if neither helped

Comment: I have used above code during execution I got below Rejection Warning 
.(node:6512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: $visibleDropdown is not defined
  
(node:6512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

Comment: This error originated because `$visibleDropdown is not defined`. Define your $visibleDropdown first

Comment: The code not shows any error in the console but unable to click the required option.               async function start() {
   let jsClick = ($element) => browser.executeScript(
        "arguments[0].click();",
        $element.getWebElement()
    );
   
       browser.sleep('7000');

    let $option = $("option[value='395']");
    browser.sleep('5000');

    await jsClick($option);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

HTML:
In select tag, add attribute `data-targetId`:

```
[attr.data-targetId]="selectTag"
```

and then use it in your test like this:

```
target='[data-targetId="selectTag"] .ng-star-inserted';
$('[role="listbox"]').click(); // click on ddListBtn to open the ddList if it's not open
let value = 'Kalahandi'; // an example
element(by.cssContainingText(target, value)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using filters:

```
this.DDOptions = element.all(by.css('.ng-star-inserted'));

exports.SelectDDOption = function (option){
this.DDOptions.filter(function (elem, index) {
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
      return text.toUpperCase() === option.toUpperCase();
    });
  }).then(function (filteredElements) {
    filteredElements[0].click();
  });
};
```

Now call this function and pass option which you want to select:

```
this.SelectDDOption('Jharsuguda');
```

Comment: Appeared Failed: this.SelectDDOption is not a function in the below code. function myFunction (){
  this.DDOptions = browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Select District')]"));
  exports.SelectDDOption = function (option){
  this.DDOptions.filter(function (elem, index) {
      return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text.toUpperCase() === option.toUpperCase();
      });
    }).then(function (filteredElements) {
      filteredElements[0].click();
    });}; 
}
  var pp= this.SelectDDOption('Jharsuguda');
  myFunction(pp);

Comment: so couple of problems with your code: 1. Do not define function inside a function : `function myFunction (){  exports.SelectDDOption = function (option){ ` since we are already using `exports.function_name` you can move it outside.

Comment: Try this code: `this.DDOptions =browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Select District')]"exports.SelectDDOption = function (option){this.DDOptions.filter(function (elem, index) {return elem.getText().then(function (text) {return text.toUpperCase() === option.toUpperCase(); });}).then(function (filteredElements) {filteredElements[0].click();});};this.SelectDDOption('Jharsuguda'); `

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option

```
const dropDown = element(by.css('div.ui-helper-hidden-accessible > select > option');

await dropDown.sendKeys('Deogarh');
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: (node:13984) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
Appeared this in console.

Comment: @PrasantaKumar Could you add your implementation

Comment: it("Select District", function() {
  console.log("This is Test No- 5");
  
  async function start() {
  
  const dropDown = element(by.css('div.ui-helper-hidden-accessible > select > option'));

  await dropDown.sendKeys('Deogarh');
  
  
  console.log("Select District...");
  browser.sleep('5000');
  
  }
  
  
 });

Answer (score 0):

i think first you should check where options are by :

- click drop-down-wrap
- wait to drop down, options are shown.
- click right mouse to an option and choose "inspect" .
  Now you can see where options are.

follow your html code

```
<select class="ng-tns-c6-189" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" aria-label=" ">
```

> there is aria-hidden field in "select"

- when you clicked drop-down-wrap, drop down and options are shown, aria-hidden field is false : (aria-hidden="false")
- when drop-down closed, options aren't shown, aria-hidden="true".

**So i think options and drop-down-wrap are same html page.**

when you known where options are, you will write code right.
Recommend,your code should be written step by step :

> var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

1. **click drop-down-wrap : choose one in two ways**

> element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget')).click();
>
> browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget')).getWebElement());

2. **browser wait until options are shown**

> browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css("select[aria-hidden="false"]"))));

or

> browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css("select[aria-hidden="false"] option:nth-child(2)"))));

or

> browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css("select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]"))));

3. **Click the option what you want**

> browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css("select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]")).getWebElement());

Comment: var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Select District')]").getWebElement()));
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Jharsuguda')]"))));
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Jharsuguda')]")).getWebElement());
  console.log("Select District...");
  browser.sleep('5000');   using this code appeared error as Failed: by.xpath(...).getWebElement is not a function

Comment: **element(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Jharsuguda')]")).getWebElement());** i think this is cause of error. why did you use this ?  there are two  clicking function what you can use . **element.click()**  , click() is protractor function . and **browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css("select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]")).getWebElement());**  , this is js function

Comment: and i think options list allways present . so, you can't use only **browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Jharsuguda')]"))));** you must to use with aria-hidden="true/false" . when option list dropped down, aria-hidden="false" . when option list disappeared, aria-hidden="true" . this make you catch event during running protractor.

Comment: Got error  TypeError: by.css(...).click is not a function when execute the below code....     var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget').click());
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget').getWebElement()));
  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]'))));
  browser.sleep('5000');
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]')).getWebElement());
  });

Comment: @PrasantaKumar ,
`var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`
//waitting element to be clickable
`browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget'))));`
`browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget')).getWebElement());`
`browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]'))));`
`browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]')).getWebElement());`

Comment: @ AquariusPotter this time appeared as script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds.  After that changed the value of CSS to p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget  div.ui-helper-hidden-accessible option.ng-tns-c9-3  But happens same ..

Comment: so, you should add timeout and message error in broswer.wait function. And we have :
`browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget'))),5000,"TIMEOUT1");`

`browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('select[aria-hidden="false"] option[value="391"]'))),5000,"TIMEOUT2");`

run grunt protractor again and see message. 
If message show "TIMEOUT1" => can't click element(by.css('p-dropdown div.ui-dropdown.ui-widget')) => CHANGE CSS ELEMENT.

Comment: if message show "TIMEOUT2" => when test run automated, you saw options list dropdown, but message show TIMEOUT2 =>  options and drop-down-wrap aren't same html page =>step by step, you will see where exactly options are : **click drop-down-wrap** -> **wait drop down list** -> **right click a option element  and choose  "inspect"** -> just see in html =]]]]

Comment: if you have teamviewer, i will help you see this. my skype is hadanhtoi@gmail.com